# Javascript Read And Set Two Domains Cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do

www.foo.com => 2 Cookies

www.foo2.com => read and Set www.foo.com cookies

entred foo2.com, reading foo.com cookies and set new cookie foo2.com

Comment: You cannot read a cookie from another domain.  That would be a huge security concern.  You can read cookies from subdomains.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-Domain Cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies)

Answer (score 0):

The Platform for Privacy Preferences Project ( P3P http://www.w3.org/P3P/ )